# Authorization headers not working with cors

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, cross-domain, fetch-api

I've been facing this issue for several days now. I'm trying to make a call to my API (api.example.com) from my website (example.com), and it works fine until I try to pass the Authorization header. At that point, it's not a simple request anymore, but a preflighted request.

However, at the end the auth headers are not sent, and the input I get is this one:

[image]

This is my front end code (JS):

```
fetch(generalInfo.url.api+"users/"+userId, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+accessToken
        },
        withCredentials: true
});
```

While this is a middleware in the API backend:

```
//Allow the cors from every domain
 module.exports = function (req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.host);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');

    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
       return res.send(200);
    }

    next();
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Options requests don't include auth headers by design.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not asking for them to pass the Auth headers, but I'm asking why it doesn't make a new GET request once it get the response and everything is ok.

Comment: because... everything is not ok. The origin doesn't match the allowed origin. The error message should be telling you at least that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> In particular, a request is preflighted if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> If, apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, or any of the other header with a name defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”),

The forbidden headers include:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

Which has `Access-Control-Request-Headers` which we can see is being sent with your request. This explains the use of a preflight.

I think the process looks ok - but in your response headers to the preflight i notice the access control allow origin is `api.myapp.com` whereas in the request if was on port `8888`. I think in the response you should have the port number if it's not 80 for http. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy. An origin is the same if:

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages. You'll see this referred to as the "scheme/host/port tuple" at times (where a "tuple" is a set of three components that together comprise a whole).

So i think the issue might be that your preflight is saying to the client that only api.myapp.com is allowed but the actual request might be made to http://api.myapp.com:8888 so the origins don't match. Or have I misunderstood what you are trying to do?

Comment: I've tried to manually add the port and the protocol, but the result hasn't changed. Still getting only the OPTIONS request @DavidGoate

Comment: Ok, it works! I was adding the wrong port (the one of the API instead of the one of the webapp). Not everything works fine! Thank you so much, man!

Comment: The normal flow is that after a successful options request providing that the CORS checks pass, the browser will issue the actual request. Can you see whether there is any error in the net developer tools console that explains why. My gut says this is simply an origin mismatch. In your example I see more than 1 origin in use.

Comment: cool, glad you got it working!

Answer (score -2):

You must remove "8888" port of your api url, the api server has to have already a port setted for api.myapp.com address